# Recovering corrupted windows folders

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

A bit of context:

My PC (Win 10) was very slow yesterday to the point where I couldn't shut it down normally, so I forced it. Then after opening it again, it waited a very long time on the login screen so I force shut it down again. Now I don't know if that caused it but the next time I opened it the BIOS refused to see the HDD. I was able to fix that by getting Windows recovery to show up intermittently and let it supposedly fix disk errors (How Windows could see the disk without the BIOS being able to see it is beyond me but maybe this is normal? I'm not an expert in this field.) Surprisingly, doing this about 10 times fixed it.

With 2 exceptions: the folders `C:\Windows` and `C:\Users` were corrupted, and now I am stuck in WinRE. I am holding back on doing a `chkdsk` due to me not having a clear idea of what it would do in this case, I really don't want thousands of file fragments with unhelpful names, having the folders as a whole would be much better.

I don't have access to another PC right now so I can't create a bootable USB, but if it's needed I can find a way. If there's something I can do without doing that it would be better though.

Is there something I can do in this case? Would `chkdsk` help? Should I try something else before resorting to it? Or is this a sign of my HDD dying?

EDIT: `chkdsk` without arguments is giving a very large amount of errors BTW.

Comment: Smells like hard disk failure.

Comment: Ah, I was afraid someone would say that. The other folders and files are totally 100% fine though. It's very strange the only folders that really count are the ones that were corrupted. I really hope there is a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something I can do in this case?

Bringing your disk to a professional recovery service or risking further dammage.
If the drive is not recognized by your BIOS that is a strong sign of a dying drive.

> Should I try something else before resorting to it? Or is this a sign
> of my HDD dying?

If your drive is appearing intermittently you could use a live linux edition to duplicate your drive using ddrescue.

> Would chkdsk help?

After consulting the SMART parameters I might run CHKDSK on a SECOND duplicate.
You can't reverse what chkdsk is doing.
Be careful, There is an issue of Microsoft delivering a faulty chkdsk version which would dammage the integrity of your file systems.

Comment: The thing is, BIOS is able to see the hard disk now. SMART looks good too. I also tinkered a bit with the hardware side of things before it was able to work properly so maybe it was that that fixed it and the problem was a connection issue. It is very strange. ddrescue is a good suggestion though, thanks for that.

Comment: Run smartmontools:
 smartctl /dev/sdx > needhelp.txt 
and post the log file. Too many ignore the obvious inside. Replace the "x" by your drive letter. Ensure good power supply - no power from a USB socket. Best solution is internal supply or docking station...

Comment: @needhelpthx - Just because bios detects doesn’t mean it’s a healthy drive, if you are not prepared to use a data recovery service, be sure you image the drive before you run any tools yourself

Comment: @r2d3 As I said, I don't have the ability to create a bootable usb right now but will update when I can. Also, could you please elaborate on "no power from a USB socket"? I'm not sure I got what you mean by that.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah I'm thinking of going in this direction.

Comment: Sorry, as you don't have a second machine to check your disk it is internally connected on the faulty machine.
When refering to power from a USB socket I am talking about an external drive that is supplied with power by an USB socket.

Comment: @r2d3 Now I got you.

Comment: @r2d3 I just realized I had a kali linux image on my second drive. Problem is I don't know how to flash the ISO to a USB drive from the WinRE command prompt. Do you happen to know any way I could do that?

Comment: @r2d3 fyi: I thought this comment warranted its own question:  https://superuser.com/questions/1642725/flashing-usb-from-winre